# How to remove fonts-ubuntu non-free package?

Tags: 20.04, fonts, gnu

I wanted to uninstall `fonts-ubuntu` package.

I used
`sudo apt remove fonts-ubuntu`,

also tried `$HOME/.local/share/fonts/` but this does not exists.
It doesnot have `fonts-ubuntu` package.

`vrms` although detects it as proprietery software. so i want to uninstall it, Help!!

Comment: What happened after you did `sudo apt remove fonts-ubuntu`? How do you know that it didn't uninstall the package? What does `dpkg-query -l fonts-ubuntu` say?

Comment: It worked sudo apt remove fonts-ubuntu , but im worrying does it remove kernel core componentes, alot of things are been removing using `sudo apt remove fonts-ubuntu`

Comment: Looks like `fonts-ubuntu` package contains a basic system font used by the GUI, so you cannot remove it without removing the whole desktop environment. All basic desktop packages depend on `fonts-ubuntu`, so it's a necessary element of every dekstop Ubuntu installation. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: because of `non-free software` , it is proprietery

Comment: This package contains only a **font** used by Ubuntu GUI. Seems quite logical to me that the font is copyrighted.

Comment: Information about the [Ubuntu Font](https://design.ubuntu.com/font/).

Answer (score 4):

Debian considers it to be non-free, while Canonical disagrees. You may want to study the `debian/copyright` file:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu/copyright
```

If you use Ubuntu, you'd better trust Canonical on this kind of licensing matters.

*Edit:*

An [adjustment](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-ubuntu/0.83-4ubuntu2) has been made to the `fonts-ubuntu` package so as from Ubuntu 21.04 `vrms` will no longer consider it to be "non-free". (On Debian `vrms` will keep listing it as "non-free", though.)

Answer (score 3):

`fonts-ubuntu` package contains the basic font used by Ubuntu GUI. It is a necessary part of every desktop Ubuntu installation, because default Ubuntu GNOME desktop environment depends on it. So in short, you cannot uninstall it if you want to have GUI. If you insist on uninstalling it, then probably the whole GUI will be uninstalled and you will be basically left with a console-only system.

Here's what the command `apt show fonts-ubuntu` says about the package:

```
Description: sans-serif font set from Ubuntu
 The Ubuntu Font Family is a set of contemporary sans-serif fonts developed
 between 2010-2011. Dalton Maag performed the font design work and
 implementation with funding from Canonical. The fonts have been the default
 fonts for Ubuntu since 2010.
```

Here are the files belonging to the package, according to command `dpkg-query -L fonts-ubuntu`:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu
/usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu/CONTRIBUTING.txt
/usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu/FONTLOG.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu/LICENCE-FAQ.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu/README.txt
/usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu/TRADEMARKS.txt
/usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/fonts-ubuntu/copyright
/usr/share/fonts
/usr/share/fonts/truetype
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-B.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-BI.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-C.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-L.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-LI.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-M.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-MI.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-RI.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Th.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-B.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-R.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
```